# Is it possible to change a Geotiffs CRS?

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, wgs84, epsg

I have created a Geotiff from the Bing Aerial photography.

As it is automatically in WGS 84 it inserts perfectly into QGIS, however this image is of no use to me outside of QGIS.

I need to convert this referencing system from WGS84 to OSGB 1936.

Is this possible at all?

I am using QGIS 1.8.0 on windows 7 and I am not great with Grass, and need to import the image into AutoCAD at some stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do the reprojecting with QGIS. `Raster -> Projection -> Transform(Reproject)` calls gdalwarp. Just select input CRS and output CRS, and a new file name.

Answer (score 1):

use the GDAL library, more specifically gdalwarp.exe. All you have to do do is to supply source -s_srs and target -t_srs projecttion along with the image. That should serve the trick.

Comment: Ok sorry where do i get the GDAL library?

Comment: It is a part of [OSGeo4W](http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/), which should be easy to install on Windows.

Comment: by searching with google (http://www.gdal.org/)

Comment: That's not necessary, as QGIS has it already incorporated.